# How to change active step comes from "reducer" when clicked elements that out of "reducer"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm working on react-redux & there are something that I can't understand. I created action & root reducer & active_step reducer & list_step reducer. I can change active step component from the navigation that mapped dynamically.

//step-list.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import {selectStep} from '../actions/index'

class StepList extends Component {
    render() {
        const renderSteps = this.props.steps.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                    <li
                        key={item.stepNumber}
                        onClick={() => {
                                this.props.selectStep(item)
                            }
                        }
                        className="step-group-item">
                        {item.title}
                    </li>
                )
            }
        )

        return (
            <ul className="step-group">
                {renderSteps}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        steps: state.steps
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({selectStep: selectStep}, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StepList)
```

//active-step.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class ActiveStep extends Component {
    render() {
        if(!this.props.step) {
            return <div className="active-step">There are no steps selected</div>
        }

        return (
            <div className="active-step">
                <h3>Step Title: {this.props.step.title}</h3>
                <h5>Step Subtitle: {this.props.step.subTitle}</h5>
                <p>Step Number: {this.props.step.stepNumber}</p>
                <div>
                    {this.props.step.content}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        step: state.activeStep
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ActiveStep)
```

//

Now, There is an another component in the main component(app.js). Its name is Footer & it has 3 buttons. I can hide & show "Back", "Next", "Success" buttons key to stepNumber. But I want active_step to change when every click next & back buttons.

// app.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import StepList from '../containers/step-list'
import ActiveStep from '../containers/active-step'
import Footer from './footer'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            whichStep: 0
        }
        this.handleBackStep = this.handleBackStep.bind(this)
        this.handleNextStep = this.handleNextStep.bind(this)
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            whichStep: nextProps.step.stepNumber
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <StepList />
                <ActiveStep whichStep={this.state.whichStep}/>
                <Footer
                    whichStep={this.state.whichStep}
                    onBackClick={this.handleBackStep}
                    onNextClick={this.handleNextStep} />
            </div>
        )
    }

    handleBackStep() {
        console.log('clicked back')
        const whichStep = this.state.whichStep
        this.setState({
            whichStep: whichStep - 1
        })
    }

    handleNextStep() {
        console.log('clicked next')
        const whichStep = this.state.whichStep
        this.setState({
            whichStep: whichStep + 1
        })
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        step: state.activeStep
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

//

I hope I explained correctly. Sorry for my bad language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, correct me if I'm wrong but you want to update the state using the reducer `active_step`.

In order to achieve that you may want to move the `selectStep` action call from `step-list.js` to `app.js`.

So this will be `step-list.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import {selectStep} from '../actions/index'

class StepList extends Component {
    render() {
        const renderSteps = this.props.steps.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                    <li
                        key={item.stepNumber}
                        onClick={() => {
                                this.props.selectStep(item)
                            }
                        }
                        className="step-group-item">
                        {item.title}
                    </li>
                )
            }
        )

        return (
            <ul className="step-group">
                {renderSteps}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default StepList
```

and this will be `app.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import StepList from '../containers/step-list'
import ActiveStep from '../containers/active-step'
import Footer from './footer'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            whichStep: 0
        }
        this.handleBackStep = this.handleBackStep.bind(this)
        this.handleNextStep = this.handleNextStep.bind(this)
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            whichStep: nextProps.step.stepNumber
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <StepList 
                    steps={this.props.steps}
                    selectStep={this.props.selectStep}
                />
                <ActiveStep whichStep={this.props.activeStep}/>
                <Footer
                    whichStep={this.props.activeStep}
                    onBackClick={this.handleBackStep}
                    onNextClick={this.handleNextStep} />
            </div>
        )
    }

    handleBackStep() {
        console.log('clicked back')
        const activeStep = this.props.activeStep
        this.props.selectStep(activeStep - 1);
    }

    handleNextStep() {
        console.log('clicked next')
        const activeStep = this.props.activeStep;
        this.props.selectStep(activeStep + 1);
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        activeStep: state.activeStep,
        steps: state.steps
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({selectStep: selectStep}, dispatch)
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

In this way you're doing the `selectStep` action always in the same place